# ¿como introducir caracteres latinos en std::cin?

Tags: c++

¿Como puedo introducir caracteres latinos en un std::cin?
por ejempo:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){

    string residencia;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "spanish");

    cout<<"Introduce tu residencia: ";
    getline(cin, residencia);

    cout<<"Tu residencia es: "<<residencia<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Al escribir por ejemplo España que contiene el carácter ñ la consola imprime esto:

[image]

Como pueden ver me introduce el carácter ¤ en vez de la ñ.
No es un error al imprimir en consola porque en este código imprime perfectamente España:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){

    string pais = "España";

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "spanish");

    cout<<"País: "<<pais<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

En este código la consola imprime esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cual es el error al introducir caracteres especiales en un std::cin o getline?

Answer (score 1):

Te está pasando eso porque estás usando `string` y `cin` en vez de `wstring` y `wcin`. Cuando lees los caracteres de la consola, y lees la letra **ñ**, esta tiene el valor numérico ASCII 164, pero los `char` que hay en el `string` solo van desde el -128 al 127. Así que la **ñ** se va de rango por estar por encima. Depurando el programa y parándolo justo después del retorno de la cadena desde la consola, la posición de la **ñ** tiene el valor -92. Si haces el cálculo, se ha ido de rango desde el último carácter 127 y ha tomado un valor negativo, con lo que al mostrar la cadena en la consola, el carácter -92 no es visible.

Solución:

Usar `wstring` que en vez de `char` es una cadena de `wchar_t` (caracteres de dos bytes), y para eso tienes que usar `wcout` y `wcin`. Tu programa quedaría así:

```
std::wstring residencia;

std::wcout << L"Introduce tu residencia: ";
getline(std::wcin, residencia);

std::wcout << L"Tu residencia es: " << residencia << std::endl;
```

Comment: Eso no es cierto, puedes usar eñes y caracteres acentuados con `cin` y `cout`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tck7CsJAFEbh2ruKARstBOskzF7CZAgXkpuQTCpxLyoWviUqgo8uCxt/iKDF15xjynJislhS74csJmsSqyIualfZONf0aygsqSZicSqPWUZjmtGgdkkQ9E@xhN9gWJTW/6FonIqivlTWNZWoaUhz77u2W8IWjnCFJyxgAwe4wAPWsIcz3OENK9jBCW7w6lr6AA "C++ (clang) – Try It Online")

Comment: La explicación de por qué le sale ese carácter en la consola no es cierta? Esta no es una posible solución?

Comment: Usar `wcin`/`wcout` en lugar de `cin`/`cout` no es una solución, porque `cin`/`cout` no es el problema, al código que he pegado de ejemplo me remito.